# How to remove HTML tags when using <bean:write />

Tags: java, html, tags, struts-1

Our project is JAVA based, so I have this, for example:

`<meta name="description" content="<bean:write name="htmlHeadDescription" ignore="true"/>"/>`

The thing is that this `htmlHeadDescription` appeared to be `HTML` and not pure text.

So - is there a way to strip the HTML tags directly?

Comment: You can't do it directly but escaping html content won't return pure text.

Answer (score 0):

I did it sort of like `manually` ... like so:

Instead of having:

```
<meta name="description" content="<bean:write name="htmlHeadDescription" ignore="true"/>"/>
```

now I have this:

```
<%
    // Remove any bad stuff - ONLY for the meta description tag ..
    request.setAttribute("htmlDescriptionStripped",
        request.getAttribute("htmlHeadDescription").toString()
            // remove any eventual remaining HTML tags ..
            .replaceAll("\\<(.*?)>","")
            // make everything on one row ..
            .replaceAll("\\s+"," ")
            // remove any eventual CSS code ..
            .replaceAll("(@media|.|#)(.*)\\{(.*)\\}","")
    );
%>
<meta name="description" content="<bean:write name="htmlDescriptionStripped" ignore="true"/>"/>
```

And it looks like it's working :)